# Font Awesome Snapchat Icon Not Showing

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-awesome

The snapchat icon for font awesome wont show on my clients live website but it works on my localhost. I'll give loads of rep to whoever helps me figure this out. I've done the obvious and updated to the latest versions and made sure everything is linked correctly. Icon is in the footer.  Website: http://ryanmagill.net/

Thanks in advance,
Jamie

Comment: Please share the relevant code and any attempts you've made to fix the issue.

Comment: There is no code to add for font awesome to work. You just link the font awesome files:

Comment: @DaniP done that hundreds of times. Is it showing for you?

Comment: @user3479267 But we need to see *your* code that isn't working.

Comment: @MikeC here is the site http://ryanmagill.net/
Icons are in the footer

Comment: I see you are using the CSS from 4.7.0, did you also update your font files to the new version?

Comment: @user3479267 You're not understanding me. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that code in your question. As soon as your site is fixed, goes down, or moves, this question becomes useless to future people.

Comment: @Kyle yes I did, the files on my localhost are identical to the live site I linked but my local version works and the live doesn't.

Comment: @MikeC ok I understand I'll do that now

Comment: This version when added to the bottom of your head tag works: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

Comment: The size of your `fontawesome-webfont.eot` that is embedded on your site is 66kB. The current Version 4.7.0 `fontawesome-webfont.eot` file from the official website is 166kB. I think you updated the CSS files but not the font files.

Comment: @michelgotta correct. updated it now, cheers!

Comment: I think this whole thread should be deleted. It is not helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of Font Awesome. I had the same problem and updating it to the latest version (4.7.0) helped.

Answer (score 0):

I wiped the old font files from the server and reuploaded the font folder to the server and then the icons worked. Must have been a weird cacheing issue on the servers end.